# When using C , argc parameter include redirection command In windows CMD?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, cmd

argc parameter in main function doesn't include redirection Command('<','>').

But, I faced a confusing problem with using double quote.

**shell(CMD)**

- I expected argc is `3` and Yes!

```
a.exe aa bb < input.txt
```

- I expected argc is also `3` ,but `5`, I just want to input `double quote` as argument.

```
a.exe \" bb < input.txt
```

My system

OS : windows 11 , shell : window CMD

Comment: Please confirm you expect argv[1] = `"` and argv[2] = `bb` in the second case.

Comment: That is an operating system/command shell issue and not a programming issue.  Hence off topic.  I suggest you ask _"How to pass a double quote as a command line argument in Windows CMD?"_ at https://superuser.com/.  The answer is I think `"\""` BTW

Comment: `cmd` is not `bash`, its quoting rules are rather bizarre.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, argv[1] = `"` and argv[2] = `bb`.

Comment: @Clifford: I first thought that, until I realized that the handling of the command line is splitted between the `cmd.exe` shell and the C run time library. A `.bat` script does not see the same arguments as a C program.

Comment: @SergeBallesta oh yes.  I have figured out a work around, posted it as an answer - despite it really being off topic, the demonstration involved code, so perhaps fair game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting is nicely defined in Unix-like systems like Linux: you can include text in single or double quotes (with different behaviour for parameter interpolation), and the backslash unconditionnaly *quotes* its following character. Furthermore, all those quotes are nicely eaten by the shell and your program receives the expected unquoted strings.

Unfortunately, Windows shell (`cmd.exe`) is not as kind. The whole command line without the redirections is passed to the program, and the C run time library handles the quoting rules. Those rules are described in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-170) and as expected a `\"` is passed as a single character string argument.

Unfortunately, the same page says:

> A string surrounded by double quote marks is interpreted as a single argument, ... If the command line ends before a closing double quote mark is found, then all the characters read so far are output as the last argument.

And I suspect that this is what happens here: the shell (`cmd.exe`) sees an odd number of double quotes and does not process any redirection. It then passes the whole command line *including the redirection* to the program and the run-time library does its best to split it into the `argv` array.

If you had typed

```
a.exe \" bb  \" < input.txt
```

you would have got 4 for `argc` and  3 parameters: `"`, `bb` and `"`. And the redirection would have worked as expected.

IMHO this is a bug in the splitting between `cmd.exe` and the C run-time library, and little if any can be done... except being aware that using quoting in Windows command line is *dangerous*, and only using it for trivial space character quoting.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a misconception that backslash is the CMD escape character.  The caret is the proper escape character in CMD shells, and always has been.  Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be treated as ordinary text.

Processes in NT do not have any concept of arguments or parameters.  Instead, a single string is passed to `CreateProcess` through the `lpCommandLine` parameter.  The C runtime extracts the C argument vector from this string obtained by calling `GetCommandLine`. As the C runtime uses the backslash as its escape character `\"` will be interpreted as a single quotation mark.

Thus, to pass a single quotation mark from CMD to a C program you must both escape the string in the shell and C runtime.  To do this use `\^"` or `^\^"`.  This is interpreted by CMD as `\"` which in turn is parsed as `"` by the C runtime.

```
a.exe \^" bb < input.txt
```

NOTE: CMD is provided for legacy application compatibility and MS-DOS compatibility.  Microsoft recommends PowerShell for modern application development.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cmd.exe command line processing is somewhat broken which is an operating system issue, but there is a kind of work around:

Given a file input.txt containing:

```
input_text
```

and test C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    char input[1024] ;
    scanf( "%s", input ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", input ) ;

    for( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        printf( "arg[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i] ) ; 
    }
}
```

Then if you modify the command line thus:

```
a.exe \" bb "< input.txt
```

The output is:

```
input_text
arg[0] = a.exe
arg[1] = "
arg[2] = bb
arg[3] =
```

So the input redirection works, but now there is an empty string fourth argument.  So still not perfect but perhaps workable.